# disable and enable click?

Tags: java, android

I have Splash Screen and button . i want if app install users click in start button and go to main activity . the problem after run app if app install go direct to main activity .. i want only check if app install enable click and if not install disable click

```
  Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_start);
    boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.facebook.android");
    if(isAppInstalled) {
        start.setEnabled(true);

        Intent Start_screen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(Start_screen);

    } else {

        start.setEnabled(false);

    }
}

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue then ?

Comment: that means you installed facebook app..thats why its directly going main activity

Comment: com.facebook.katana use this and check

Comment: @ADM why go direct to main activity ?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh remove but after click button don't go to the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want if app install users click in start button

Your startActivity event is not in the click listener of the enabled button, therefore it immediately goes to the next Activity

Try `start.setOnClickListener`, and *then* check if the app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_start);
boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.facebook.android");
if(isAppInstalled) {
    start.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    start.setEnabled(false);
} 
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent Start_screen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(Start_screen);
} 
});
```